# Would Ryuk have died if he had killed the SPK?

Tags: death-note

In the manga, Light begs Ryuk, to kill everyone in that room. So let's say, Ryuk would have killed the Japanese Task Force and the SPK. Would Ryuk die after he killed them?

Comment: Possibly yes, but I don't remember the DN rule about killing for a human well enough to give an answer atm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rule LVIII:

1) By manipulating the death of a human that has influence over another human's life, that human's original life span can sometimes be lengthened.

2) If a god of death intentionally does the above manipulation to effectively lengthen a human's life span, the god of death will die, but even if a human does the same, the human will not die.

This seems pretty explicit to me.  Note that this seems to refer to killing with the death note but if a god of death kills by any other means he is given an "Extreme Level" punishment and then is executed.

**What's love got to do with it? Nothing**

Comment: So he would have died only if he had intended to lengthen Light's lifespan?

Comment: Yes... but that is why light asked him to kill them.  If he killed them for fun after light died, he would not die but that would serve no purpose beyond just randomly slaughtering anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Doubt it. Ryuk did not love light (which is the requirement for dying).  Ryuk was just hanging around for the entertainment. Even if he killed everyone in the room it was probably to extend his entertainment. He however would never do this because he was impartial to light and had explained this to him in the very beginning. Whenever he did help light it was because he didn't want to be further bothered.  In this case saving light would have caused him more work.

Comment: well if ryuk would have killed the spk and the task force, he could have watched how light would make his ''new world.''

Comment: The wording of the rule is "an individual he favors".  Even if it is just for his fun, it would mean he favors Light for his ability to entertain him.

Comment: Maybe but the rule comes down to if he's doing to help light or doing it for other reasons. If you look at it as just because he killed them light gets inadvertently helped that would apply basically to a lot of scenarios worldwide where shinigami killing someone may accidentally help someone else out.  It comes down more to you're doing it for the sole goal of helping a person out rather than other motives like your own entertainment or extending your life.

Comment: Doesn't this answer goes against the Question? It was asked if he would die SUPPOSED he DID killed them. Not if he would do it.

Comment: *Love is blind.* Rem suggests when talking to Misa that Shinigami know full well what happens to them if they lengthen a human's lifespan by preventing their death. since you can't bargain with a Shinigami to have them risk their existence to save you Love is about the only think that will make them risk it. Love isn't a requirement per say but more of a reason to explain the action

Comment: To clarify a comment i made here earlier which is different from my answer, another rule than the one I quoted specifically refers to them dying of they use it to save someone they "favor". The more general rule obviously superceeds in cases where that is not the case but the punishment is identical.